# Latex align error?

Tags: align

Why does the following code give me this error?:

```
"Extra } or forgotten \right)"
```

I have been through it and cannot work out why.

```
\begin{align}
C(t,xxx,\tau,N,X)&=N\Phi\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left[-(1+X_{\tau_{i}})P(t,T_{i})\left(\frac{\ln\frac{P(t,T_{i-1})}{(1+X_{\tau_{i}}P(t,T_{i})}}{\Sigma(t,T_{i-1},T_{i})}-\frac{1}{2}\Sigma(t,T_{i-1},T_{i})\right)\\
&+P(t,T_{i-1})[\left(\frac{\ln\frac{P(t,T_{i-1})}{(1+X_{\tau_{i}})P(t,T_{i})}}{\Sigma(t,T_{i-1},T_{i})}-\frac{1}{2}\Sigma(t,T_{i-1},T_{i})\right)\right]
\end{align}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you're missing a matching `\right` delimiter to one of your `\left` delimiters.

Also, you cannot break `\left` and `\right` across lines inside `align` (or any math environment for that matter). You need to do this manually by using a fake opposing delimiter and introducing the necessary false heights to obtain equivalent delimiters. However, an easier alternative would be to use non-matching "big" operators:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \rlap{$C(t,xxx,\tau,N,X)$}\hspace{2em} & \nonumber \\
    &= N\Phi\sum_{i=1}^{n}
      \Bigg[-(1+X_{\tau_{i}})P(t,T_{i})
        \Bigg(\frac{\ln\frac{P(t,T_{i-1})}{(1+X_{\tau_{i}}P(t,T_{i})}}{\Sigma(t,T_{i-1},T_{i})}-\frac{1}{2}\Sigma(t,T_{i-1},T_{i})\Bigg)\\
    &\phantom{{}={}} {}+P(t,T_{i-1})\Bigg[
      \Bigg(\frac{\ln\frac{P(t,T_{i-1})}{(1+X_{\tau_{i}})P(t,T_{i})}}{\Sigma(t,T_{i-1},T_{i})}-\frac{1}{2}\Sigma(t,T_{i-1},T_{i})\Bigg)\Bigg]\Bigg]
\end{align}
\end{document}​
```

The use of `\hspace` in the first line is to make the equation fit within the text block width. Also note the use of `\phantom{{}={}}` to obtain the correct spacing for the second numbered equation.

Comment: I see! that is very useful to know. Thank you very much!